# Submit form sem button. Apenas quando input estiver preenchido

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Então galera, gostaria de saber como faz para enviar um formulário sem botão de envio ou sem clicar em algo. Vi em um site um `input` onde após preencher com um valor, ele da submit no formulário.

Tentei fazer o mesmo mas não consegui. Eu quero que ele envie quando o formulário quando o quantidade de caracteres do `input` seja maior que cinco.

Detalhe: no `form` só tem um `input` para digitar o valor, dessa forma:

```
<script>
    (document).ready(function(){
      $('#campo').on('input', function(){
        $('#campo').prop('submit', $(this).val().length < 3);
      });
    });
</script>

<label>Campo:</label>
    <input id="campo" type="text" maxlength="3">
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta criar uma função para o evento [`oninput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput) para verificar se o tamanho do `input` é maior que cinco e enviar o formulário. Veja o código abaixo:

```js
function checksInput() {
    const input = document.getElementById("code");
    const form = document.getElementById("myForm");

    if (input.value.length > 5) {
        form.submit();
    }
}

document.getElementById("code").oninput = checksInput;
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
    <input id="code" placeholder="Digite o código do produto"/>
</form>
```

Comment: `length > 4`, pois começa do 0... 0,1,2,3,4 (5)

Comment: No caso dele é `length > 5` porque ele quer que o input tenha um tamanho maior que cinco.

Comment: então ta certo :D

Answer (score 0):

Olá, teve a resposta acima com Javascript puro, vou deixar um exemplo com o jQuery também, só que no caso optei por deixar a condição **igual a 5** pq daí envia apenas os 5 caracteres:

```js
$(() => {
  $('#campo').on('input', function() {
    if($(this).val().length == 5) $('form').submit()
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <label>Campo:</label>
  <input id="campo" type="text">
</form>
```